# static initialization block vs constructor java

Tags: java

```
class prog
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("s1");
    }
    prog()
    {
        System.out.println("s2");
    }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        prog p = new prog();
    }
}
```

Output is

```
s1
s2
```

As per the output, it seems that static initialization block gets executed before the default constructor itself is executed.

What is the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [static initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) are executed, when [the class is initialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4).

[Class loading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) is a separate step, that happens slightly earlier. Usually a class is loaded and then immediately initialized, so the timing doesn't really matter most of the time. But it *is* possible to load a class without initializing it (for example by using [the three-argument `Class.forName()` variant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)).

No matter which way you approach it: a class will *always* be fully initialized at the time you create an instance of it, so the `static` block will already have been run at that time.

Answer (score 36):

`Static block` executed once at the time of class-loading & initialisation by JVM and constructor is called at the every time of creating instance of that class.

If you change your code -

```
public static void main(String...args){
    prog p = new prog();
    prog p = new prog();
}
```

you'll get output -

```
s1 // static block execution on class loading time
s2 // 1st Object constructor
s2 // 2nd object constructor
```

Which clarifies more.

Answer (score 6):

That is right static initialization is being done when class is loaded by class loader and constructor when new instance is created

Answer (score 0):

Static block one time execution block..
it executes while class loading..

when object is created for a class constructor executes..